# is there a way to split a single browser's window/tab into 2 viewing areas?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

I have to frequently visit a webpage that contains a table with thousands of lines.  The first row contains the names of the columns. Many of the columns are numerical values.

Once you scroll/page down, the first line is gone, and with it the headers.

Is there a way to horizontally split a Firefox/Explorer window, so that in the upper part you keep the first row with the columns' names, and you scroll up/down the lower window?

I don't have control over the design of the website.

Thanks.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/tile-tabs/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try the [Split Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4287) addon.

Comment: I installed the add-on, tried it, and does exactly what I need and more.  You can easily slide the (thin) dividing line up/down, or left/right if you choose to partition the screen vertically.  Nice add-on!  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no longer maintained and not compatible with latest versions of Firefox.

Comment: The latest web extension of the same is available here - [Split Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tile-tabs-we)

Answer (score 2):

If you have any experience with Javascript you could write a [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script for Firefox that pops the header row into a static (non-scrolling) area (div) on the screen.

You would need to get enough identifying information about the header row to be able to select it using Javascript - you could use the [Firebug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to GreaseMonkey.  In this instance the SplitBrowser add-on does what I need, but good to know about GreaseMonkey for more unique customizations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the windowing options of Firefox and IE, but I know how you could do this in Opera.  I assume that similar capabilities are available in Firefox.

You could open the document in two separate tabs and then go to Window -> Arrange -> Tile Horizontally

Then, use the bottom window to scroll independently of the other.

Comment: Thanks for the info Chris.  Sounds like Opera by default provides the feature that in Firefox you have to add via the Split-Browser add-on.

Comment: Most people don't realize that there's a right-click menu on the tabs in Opera that gives you some wonderful tricks.

Comment: Chris, this means that if the user editd data on the table into a tab, the other tab doesn't update: columns headers could be a mess and don't match anymore the tbody of the table. But still this answer is interesting to show side by side different pages

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Side-View Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/side-view/) + [disabling the sidebar width limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77193495/658497) is working perfectly within a single Firefox window:

[image]