# Windows explorer split window

Tags: software-rec, windows-explorer, split-window

Is there a similar addon or tool such as the SplitTab addon for Firefox for windows explorer?

Neither of these questions provides what I need.

SplitTab in the browser:

[is there a way to split a single browser's window/tab into 2 viewing areas?](https://superuser.com/questions/9598/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-single-browsers-window-tab-into-2-viewing-areas)

Windows Explorer Replacements:

https://superuser.com/questions/90/what-is-your-favourite-replacement-of-windows-exporer-for-managing-files-and-such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) has, by default, a dual folder view.

[image: Screenshot of FreeCommander]

It can be customized to be a horizontal side-by-side view as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a complete replacement.  I have used for many years Directory Opus after spending far too much time in Total Commander and various other replacements.

Dopus is by far the most actively developed, capable, customizable and stable choice that I am aware of.  Check it out http://www.gpsoft.com.au ... caution it is not free, but you can give it a 90 day trial just skip registering for the eval for 30 days.

Screenshots at http://www.gpsoft.com.au/program/screenshots.html

But if you have found a solution elsewhere to your question let us know, I too keen for such a mod.