# How to split window in Windows 7, like in Ubuntu Nautilus (F3 key)

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu

I love the Ubuntu feature when I press F3, two windows appear so that I can drag and drop files between different folders.

Can I get this functionality in Windows 7? Like an extension or something?

### Note :

I know I can open the two folders and press Windows + Left and Windows + Right, so that they split the window. However, they also contain the navigator bar (on the left) twice, so it is not very space efficient. Also I have to minimize them separately. So I could really use another way, and maybe even splitting up to 4 windows ?

Comment: You can hide the navigator for one of the windows to get some of the space back.

Comment: Yes that's a solution for the first issue (but not the second one, i.e. having two separate windows to minimize). Moreover, when I hide the navigator, then I will need to unhide it when I open the 3 rd window, and it will cycle on. So I'm looking for a permanent solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The **same Question** at the [Windows explorer split window](https://superuser.com/questions/9749/windows-explorer-split-window) , you find your answer ,the answer is [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) , or just [cascaded](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11073/stupid-geek-tricks-tile-or-cascade-multiple-windows-in-windows-7/)