# Is there a way to split the browser in two sides?

Tags: windows-7, browser, browser-addons

I'm using a 22' screen and usually when I open a web page, it gets centered in the middle and there's a lot of empty space at it. I guess that there might be some plugin that splits the browser in two browsers. I know I could do it with two instances of the same browser. But it would be annoying when minimizing.

[image]

I'd like to have the following result:

[image]

Comment: @Bernhard The question is on topic here — there's a specific problem to solve, not polling for the best plugin to do something.

Comment: Checkout existing question and answers: https://superuser.com/a/1810389/141314

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and obvious solution is to open a second window and use Aero Snap to move each window to one half of the screen.

If you want to stay with just one window, Chrome and Firefox have some add-ons that will do this:

#### Chrome:

- [Split Screen](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/split-screen/fdomcmiaceknibplahmcgmcpdkhmbgej?hl=en)

#### Firefox:

- [Tile Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tile-tabs/)
- [Split Panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/split-pannel/)