# how to split the google chrome browser into 2 panes?

Tags: browser, browser-addons

It was previously asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/720617/is-there-a-way-to-split-the-browser-in-two-sides) and "[Split Screen](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/split-screen/eachfleknamlcepmplpdghagngjfjkin?hl=en)" extension is recommended.

However when I use it the error message comes out: "For security reasons, framing is not allowed. click OK to remove the frame"

[image]

Any work-around or other ways?

Update after @jofro 's reply:
I tried disable all other extensions and it still fails.

The setting page shows an error which I don't understand:

> Warning: This extension failed to modify the response header
>   "X-Frame-Options" of a network request because the modification
>   conflicted with another extension (*Split Screen*).

[image]

It fails regardless of whether the "Allow access to file URLs" is checked or not.

However, if I try use "Split Window" to browser google.com on the left side and wikipedia on the right, it works!

Just to note my configurations: 
Google Chrome: Version 35.0.1916.153 m
OS: Windows XP Professional SP3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i search via google and get the impressesion that message could be caused by a another third party addon.

If you look at this site: [there are some hints.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140314/framing-is-not-allowed) My advice. Try to deactivate all other plugins in chrome and let only SplitScreen enabled. Restart chrome. Try again.

If its working than, try to activate step by step the other addons to identify the causing one.

Kind regards,
jf

Comment: thanks for the reply, it's actually working! seems something wrong with stack exchange websites.