# Google Chrome Split Pane View

Tags: google-chrome

***I am wondering if there is a way to browse a webpage with a split pane view*** *(similar to how excel has the ability to split panes to see different parts of the same spreadsheet).*

Google searching brings up tons of extensions for having multiple pages side by side in the same tab, but ***I want to see multiple sections of the same web page at the same time*** (i.e. viewing the top portion of the page at the same time as much further down).

Any thoughts or ideas for me?

*(I am also open to switching browsers if a different browser has this feature. I tagged with Chrome because it is my current preferred browser right now. I am using Win7)*

P.S. I've looked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/773073/how-to-split-the-google-chrome-browser-into-2-panes) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/720617/is-there-a-way-to-split-the-browser-in-two-sides) but the recommendations here don't appear to do what I want and/or they contain dead links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are open to using a different browser...
This is a standard feature of the [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) browser.

You can [tile tabs](https://vivalditips.com/efficiency/tab-tiling/en) side-by-side or in a grid within the browser window.  There is nothing to stop you using the same web site in two such tabs.

From their help pages...

[image: Vivaldi help page on tab tiling]

Comment: Very cool. I'll check it out. I've never heard of this browser before, and I definitively am intrigued. :)

Comment: I tested this browser out and it does what you demonstrate. I was hoping to ultimately find a browser or extension that would show the same page instance with a split pane type view, but in the absence of anything like that being available, this definitely is a step in the right direction.  Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: Accepted your answer since it was the most helpful one so far. Thanks again for the recommendation.

Comment: This is great. I wish there was to just split page into two like visual studio or other editors.